# How to test parameterized scope method using rspec(v3.4.1) in rails(v4.2.5)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3

Model:

> ```
>  scope :recent, ->(n) {where(:created_at => 6.months.ago..Time.now).order('created_at DESC').limit(n)}
> ```

I would do something like this in Rspec:

> ```
> before(:each) do  
>   @song = double(Song,id: 1, name: "Vegan artisan.", album_id: 1, artist_id: 20, created_at: "2016-03-04 13:15:36", updated_at: "2016-03-04 13:15:36")  
> end              
> it "should return the recent most songs within range" do   
>   Song.stub_chain(:where,:order,:limit).with(created_at:6.months.ago..Time.now).with('created_at DESC').with(2).and_return([@song,@song])  
>   Song.recent.should == [@song,@song]  
> end
> ```

The above case is failing , giving the below mentioned error:

> ```
>  ArgumentError:
>    wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
> ```

I tried different approaches, but still hard luck. Any help on this would   be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recent` scope requires you to pass a parameter that limits the search result, thus you need to change this line appropriately:

```
Song.recent(2).should eq([@song,@song])
```

or

```
expect(Song.recent(2)).to match_array([@song,@song])
```